# mysql event date sorting

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a simple event php script as an exercise which utilizes the mysql database. 
I'm trying to list all future festivals by date however it is listing no festivals.

The $nowdate_? variables are today's day, month, and year.

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     Festivals
WHERE    startdate_y <= " . $nowdate_y . " 
AND      startdate_m >= " . $nowdate_m . "
AND      startdate_d > " . $nowdate_d . "
ORDER BY startdate_y asc,startdate_m asc,startdate_d asc 
LIMIT    0,15
```

Am I approaching this incorrectly in the query?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not have a single startdate column instead of splitting it into 3 columns?

Comment: @Barmar: probably to fulfill 1st NF requirement. But it might pay off to have also the full date if this query is very frequent and includes many records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not compare the date in parts.

You need

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(
          STR_TO_DATE(
              CONCAT_WS('-', startdate_y, startdate_m, startdate_d),
              '%Y-%m-%d'),
          '%Y-%m-%d')
      > CURRENT_DATE
```

The above expression might need a bit of fixing depending on what is exactly in the date fields.

Comment: You need to ensure that 1-digit numbers get a 0 prefix.

Comment: indeed, it only came to me after posting. I'll fix it in a while.